Is rethrow in multi-catch formally defined?
Why is throw e allowed, but not throw a, in the following case?
  void test() {
    try {
      System.out.println();
    } catch (Error | RuntimeException e) {
      var a = e;
      //throw a; unreported exception Throwable; must be caught or declared to be thrown
      throw e;
    }
  }

All of this intuitively makes sense, but from JLS 14.20

A multi-catch clause can be thought of as a sequence of uni-catch clauses. That is, a catch clause where the type of the exception parameter is denoted as a union D1|D2|...|Dn is equivalent to a sequence of n catch clauses where the types of the exception parameters are class types D1, D2, ..., Dn respectively.
In the Block of each of the n catch clauses, the declared type of the exception parameter is lub(D1, D2, ..., Dn).

Since lub(Error,RuntimeException) is Throwable, the code above should be equivalent to:
    try {
      System.out.println();
    } catch (Error e) {
      Throwable lub = e;
      throw lub;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      Throwable lub = e;
      throw lub;
    }

(which obviously doesn't compile)
Moreover, the type of the a is the type of e "when treated as if it did not appear in an assignment context" (JLS 14.4.1), but as shown above it's not the same as the type of e.
Is there anything I've overlooked?

Edit: this is not a duplicate of Why is it legal to re-throw a Throwable in certain cases, without declaring it? because this question is specific to multi-catch (which isn't discussed there) and arises due to a misunderstanding of a specific fragment of the JLS that addresses multi-catch. The answers provided in this question helped me to connect the dots :)

This is described in 11.2.2. This basically boils down to "exception parameters in catch (...) are a special case".
Our goal is to show throw e; compiles. We start with this line in 11.2.3:

It is a compile-time error if a method or constructor body can throw some exception class E when E is a checked exception class and E is not a subclass of some class declared in the throws clause of the method or constructor.

So we want to show that the try statement in test cannot throw Throwable. Note that "can throw" in this context is a rigorously defined term. According to 11.2.2,

A try statement can throw an exception class E iff either:

The try block can throw E, [...]

Some catch block of the try statement can throw E and either no finally block is present or the finally block can complete normally;
or

A finally block is present and can throw E.



Only the second point is relevant here. Let's show that the catch block cannot throw Throwable. Namely, throw e; cannot throw Throwable.

A throw statement whose thrown expression is a final or effectively
final exception parameter of a catch clause C can throw an exception
class E iff:

E is an exception class that the try block of the try statement which declares C can throw; and

E is assignment compatible with any of C's catchable exception classes; and

E is not assignment compatible with any of the catchable exception classes of the catch clauses declared to the left of C in the same try
statement.



throw e; here immediately fails the first bullet point, so we can conclude that throw e; cannot throw Throwable.
If it were throw a;, then the above doesn't apply, but another clause does:

A throw statement whose thrown expression has static type E and is not a final or effectively final exception parameter can throw E or any exception class that the thrown expression can throw.


The Java compiler is intelligent enough to recognize that catching e and throwing e will mean you throw RuntimeException or Error, and thus not a checked exception that is not declared.
On the other hand, the type of var a is inferred to Throwable (and not to Error | RuntimeException as you may think, as such a declaration is not actually valid in that context!), and thus throw a means that you throw a Throwable, and therefor the compiler doesn't know for sure that you're not throwing a checked exception, and as such it raises the error.
Could the compiler be changed to recognize this? Probably yes. Would it make sense to do so? Probably not (or at least, the value of doing is probably not worth the investment).
This follows from the rules specified in 14.18 The throw Statement combined with 11.2.2 Exception Analysis of Statements.
It specifically follows from this rule in 11.2.2 for throw e:

A throw statement whose thrown expression is a final or effectively
final exception parameter of a catch clause C can throw an exception
class E iff:

E is an exception class that the try block of the try statement which declares C can throw; and
E is assignment compatible with any of C's catchable exception classes; and
E is not assignment compatible with any of the catchable exception classes of the catch clauses declared to the left of C in the same try
statement.


On the other hand, for throw a, the following applies:

A throw statement (§14.18) whose thrown expression has static type E and is not a final or effectively final exception parameter can throw E or any exception class that the thrown expression can throw.


The salient part of the JLS is 11.2.2 which says:

A throw statement whose thrown expression is a final or effectively
final exception parameter of a catch clause C can throw an exception
class E iff:

E is an exception class that the try block of the try statement which declares C can throw; and

E is assignment compatible with any of C's catchable exception classes; and

...



That explains why the following will throw either Error or RuntimeException:
  void test1() {
    try {
      ...
    } catch (Error | RuntimeException e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }

But in the following:
  void test2() {
    try {
      ...
    } catch (Error | RuntimeException e) {
      var a = e;
      throw a;
    }
  }

the inferred type of a is Throwable (the upper bound).  And that will result in a compilation error ... if the enclosing method is not declared as throwing Throwable.
For the var declaration, JLS 14.4.1 says this:

If the LocalVariableType is var, then let T be the type of the initializer expression when treated as if it did not appear in an assignment context, and were thus a standalone expression (§15.2). The type of the local variable is the upward projection of T with respect to all synthetic type variables mentioned by T (§4.10.5).

That is hard to parse, but my understanding is that "the upward projection of T" is the same type referred to as the "least upper bound" type.  In the test2 example that would be Throwable.
Note the JLS text you quoted in your question is illustrative not normative text.  And it doesn't describe what happens when you (re-)throw the caught exception.
